# Extracting data from a list using a for loop

Tags: python, arrays, list, loops, csv

I am quite new to python. For an exercise i am reading in data from a csv file and storing it in a list. Having trouble then accessing elements in the list and storing them as variables thereafter.

The data contained in the file will be an ID, followed by two sets of coordinates

```
ID, x1, y1, x2, y2
```

I need to be able to extract the data from my list to be used in calculations later on. hoping to loop over the list for multiple lines to be calculated.

Any help is appreciated!

Cheers

Comment: Welcome Jakeb to Stack Overflow. Please read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Give a minimal example and show what you have tried so far. **Search** other questions on this site. Your current question will not get much input without this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) library

```
with open('/path/to/file.csv', 'r') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        ID, x1, y1, x2, y2 = row
```

Comment: Thanks mate, that's a big help. Am I able to skip the first row if the data has a header line? Or is it easiest to just delete the row from the reader?

Comment: To skip the first row, type `next(reader)` before the `for` loop.

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to collect your data in a dictionary (perhaps the `id` field can be the key) and collect all coordinates for that particular id.

Here is one such approach:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

data = defaultdict(list)

with open('your_file.csv') as f:
   reader = csv.reader(f)
   next(reader) # skips the header row
   for row in reader:
     data[row[0]].append(((row[1],row[2]),(row[3],row[4])))
```

---

Based on your comment:

> How would i then access the values to compute the following:
>   sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2) for each of the two lines (Example1 and
>   Example2) contained in the dictionary?

You can do the calculations as you are reading the file, and just store the results by the `id` value:

```
for row in reader:
    id, x1, y1, x2, y2 = row
    # We have to convert the numbers from a string to floats for the calculation
    result = sqrt(float(x2)-float(x1))**2 + (float(y2)-float(y1))**2
    data[id].append(result)
```

Then, you can just print the results:

```
for id, results in data.iteritems():
    print('For ID: {}'.format(id))
    for row, result in enumerate(results):
        print('\t{} - {}'.format(row+1, result))
```

Comment: Thanks mate. 

So the code is putting the data into a dictionary:
`{'Example1': [(('2', '3'), ('2', '15')], 'Example2': [(('0', '0'), ('10', '20')]}`

How would i then access the values to compute the following:
`sqrt((x2-x1)**2 + (y2-y1)**2)`
 for each of the two lines (Example1 and Example2) contained in the dictionary?

Comment: Well, first you would have to convert the numbers (which are strings) into integers/floats depending on what kind of data you have. To do that, you can just modify the reader, like this `data[row[0]].append(((float(row[1]),float(row[2])),(float(row[3]),float(row[4]))))`; then simply loop through the dictionary and do your calculations; `for tag, values in data.iteritems():`; or you can do the calculations in the loop itself.